# How do I share a Google Sheet without showing my script while allowing users to copy and paste the data?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to share my google sheet to my community. I want the users to be able to copy and paste (ctrl+c) my data in the sheets as they wish but I don't want to expose my script in the backend. The current Google sharing options doesn't have that option. If I turn off `Viewers and commenters can see the option to download, print, and copy` option, they can't even use ctrl+c.

Comment: What does your script do? I am asking this because you can have a standalone script not contained into the spreadsheet that just makes reference to the spreadsheet to work the same way, but that would depend on what your script does and if it is strictly necessary for the script to be contained in the sheet for it to work or not.

Comment: Another option is to share a copy of the file without the script to the users.

Comment: I have some initial data in the sheets and the other data would be generated using those initial data. The calculation functions are stored in the script and called in the cells to generate the data. And the functions are shared among multiple sheets.

Comment: Do you use any particular trigger, or do you run the script manually whenever you want to calculate something?

Comment: I call the functions like this in the cells `=calculateFunc(INDEX(F2),INDEX(G2),INDEX(H2))`

Comment: Oh so you use it as a custom function. The thing in this particular use case is that the script needs to be  contained within the sheet in order to call the function. There may be a workaround by deploying the main script that performs the calculation as a library, and then in your sheet you just add the library and create a simple script that calls the function. That way you can still use it a custom function and only the script calling the library will be exposed. Nobody will have access to the code of the library.

Comment: Give me a couple minutes and I can post an answer explaining it a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial workaround you can use to hide your script is to create a standalone script first that performs the calculations that you need, and then deploy it as a library in Apps Script, for example:

#### Sample script 1

[image]

This would need to be deployed as a library(see instructions below) within Google Apps Script and you would need to take note of the library URL to get the ID. Sample URL

```
https://script.google.com/macros/library/d/1KTBv....ZIWCMVh-oAFbfhQp....v3M3Tfn6Npmot0bmtnvVlBU/1
```

With this you take what is after `/d/` and before `/1` and you have your ID. This ID is used in your main spreadsheet to add the library to it:

[image]

Once you paste the ID and click `Look up` you add the library and define a word to call it within your code. After that you can just easily call the library and the function needed to perform an operation. For example:

#### Sample script 2

[image]

If you see, the actual operation is being don within the code of the library that will be hidden to the users, and in the main spreadsheet I am just calling the function from the library. This way you will still have a script but will hide the whole main script from other users as they will only see something similar to script #2 in from my examples.

#### References:

- [How to deploy a script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/deployments#create_a_versioned_deployment)

Comment: Where do I create the standalone script? The default script is called `Code.gs`. Do I create a new script in the same location?

Comment: You would just need to go to script.google.com and create a new project. The second script is the one contained within Google Sheets that you can create by opening the file then going to Extensions >> Apps Script.

Comment: Thank you, tested and worked. Users can now use the ctrl+c command to copy the data and making a copy of the spreadsheet will result in a bunch of ERROR on cells that called the custom functions.